# Customizing the background of a UITableViewCell works, except on its first touch down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm customizing the background of a UITableViewCell and it's working ok except for the cell's first touch down.

The view loads with one of the cells already being selected and has the correct custom background.  The other unselected cells also have the correct custom background:
[image]

If I touch down on the Customers cell for the **first** time, it shows the default selected cell background (plain blue):

[image]

When I release the touch, it turns into the custom background.  On subsequent touch downs, it shows the correct custom background.

The cell is a subclass of UITableViewCell and I'm setting the background in the `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if(selected)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad-list-item-selected.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = imageView;
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad-list-element.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        cell.backgroundView = imageView;
    }
}
```

How to correct this so the custom background shows up on the first touch down also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you create your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set your default `selectedBackgroundView` there instead of doing it for the first time in `setSelected`.

Or alternatively call the `setSelected` super method **after** you set the `selectedBackgroundView` property in your override.

Comment: Thanks.  Customizing at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` did it.